# How do I import the necessary Jinterface packages in Java?

Tags: java, erlang

I understand that I need to import the packages in

```
import com.ericsson.otp.erlang.*;
```

To run Jinterface in Java, this is not included in Java's default libraries but in Erlang's. How do I access this library? Which path should I use? I've google it but found nothing. I am using Ubuntu 13.10. The above code is not enough for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done any Java development before, then you know that you should add `OtpErlang.jar` to your application's class path.

You can do this in the command line, Ant, Maven, Gradle or even in your IDE.

Command line example:

```
javac -classpath OtpErlang.jar YourGame.java
```

I use OS X and `OtpErlang.jar` is under:

> /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R16B03-1/lib/erlang/lib/jinterface-1.5.8/priv/OtpErlang.jar

Keep in mind that you need to include `OtpErlang.jar` also when you run your game.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the [Jinterface users Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/users_guide.html), they give an example of compiling the Java code.